# How do you exclude a property in a persistent object in db4o using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, db4o, object-oriented-database

Since "[Transient]" does not really work on properties. What do I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db4o doesn't care about properties. It cares about fields.

I guess you are trying to use "[auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)", correct?

Until we improve db4o to fully understand auto-implemented properties my best bet is to use *normal* properties for such cases.

**[edited]**

```
class Item
{
    [Transient] 
    private int serviceLength; 

    public int ServiceLength
    {
       get { return serviceLength; } 
       set { serviceLength = value; } 
    }
}
```

**[/edited]**

We do have [an open issue](http://tracker.db4o.com/browse/COR-1799) to add support for automatic properties. If that's important for you, please, vote on it.

Best

Adriano

Comment: Added your comment as a sample.

Comment: Please update me when we have a development on the issue, thanks.